# Is my breadboard faulty?

Tags: breadboard

I'm using a breadboard to prototype my projects. On one pin of an MCU, which is an output, I'm getting a 0-3.3V signal, as expected. However, another pin has a 20mVp-p signal almost matching the other one, but lower in amplitude. Where is this coming from? Has my board got a weak short or something like that?

Comment: Can you isolate that it is the breadboard? Like can you pull the 2nd pin out of the board and see if there is this same signal?

Comment: The pin is set as an input, is there anything else I can do? it's going to be tricky to remove only one pin without damaging the MCU, and I only have one spare.

Comment: I have found DIP components very easy to just bend one lead and then bend it back.

Comment: You can also change where the MCU is located on the bread board as well as take the MCU out and measure the resistance between the 2 rows.

Comment: is that input just floating? if so, and you put a 10k to one of the rails, it should suppress some of the noise.

Comment: @JustJeff I will try that, good idea.

Comment: I tried it and the noise dropped to zero but has been replace by spikes at the transition points between on and off.

Comment: As kellenjb says, this is coupling. as you decrease the inductance and resistance of your termination it will decrease those spikes, I would guess you are using a through hole resistor for termination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spikes you are seeing are just an effect of your breadboard allowing coupling. This is expected with any breadboard.

Comment: Capacitive coupling, in particular.

Comment: if a rising signal causes positive spikes, it is capacitive. It could be reverse traveling noise otherwise that is reflecting off of a low impedance driver.